# Ajax with plugins returns 0

Tags: plugins, ajax, rest-api

I'm trying to create buttons in `edit-comments` table, and I want to use Ajax with a plugin for the task.

This is the code of the plugin under plugins/no_email/no_email.php :

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Approve Comment but don't send email
  Plugin URI: ""
  Description: Approve commnet or Trash Commnet but don't send the email.
  Author: MNTS
  Version: 1.1
  Text Domain: delete_comment
  Author URI: http://www.mnts.com/
 */

add_action('wp_ajax_deteletcomment', 'deteletcomment');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_deteletcomment', 'deteletcomment');
function deteletcomment() {
    echo "test";
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_approvecomment', 'approvecomment');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_approvecomment', 'approvecomment');
function approvecomment() {
    echo "test";
    exit;
}
```

And this is the client code under themes/the_current_theme/functions.php :

```
function addCommentColumns($columns)
{
    ?> <script>
    function commentdel(id) {
    console.log('id: ' + id);
        var data = {
           'action': 'deteletcomment',
           'comment_id': id
        };
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        console.log('del response: ' + response);
    })
    }

    function commentapprove(id) {
    console.log('id: ' + id);
        var data = {
            'action': 'approvecomment',
            'comment_id': id
        };
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        console.log('approve response: ' + response);
    })
    }
    </script> <?php

    $columns['comment_action'] = __( 'No email' );
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns', 'addCommentColumns', 10, 2);


function comment_action_column_buttons( $column, $comment_ID )
{
    if ( 'comment_action' == $column ) {
    // document.location.reload(); // ignore this line please !
    ?>
    <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="commentapprove(<?php echo $comment_ID ?>);">Approve but don't email</a><br>
    <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="commentdel(<?php echo $comment_ID ?>); ">Trash but don't email</a>
    <?php
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_comments_custom_column', 'comment_action_column_buttons', 10, 2 );
```

On success, I should see 'test' in JS console, but all I see is fails:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the plugin is activated? 0 response means there is no function found hooked to that action.

Comment: I guess not.. How can  I know? There's nothing (that I found) in https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin @Milo

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your AJAX requests into a REST endpoint to get rid of this common 0 response. All you have to register 2 REST routes for your requests:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    //Path to approve comment
    register_rest_route( 'john_doe/v2', '/approve_comment/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'approve_my_comment' 
    ) );
    // Path to delete comment
    register_rest_route( 'john_doe/v2', '/remove_comment/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'remove_my_comment' 
    ) );
});
```

And now, in your callback functions:

```
function approve_my_comment(){
    return 'Approved';
}
function remove_my_comment(){
    return 'removed';
}
```

Now you will be able to run your functions by visiting `example.com/wp-json/john_doe/v2/approve_comment`.

That's all. No more dilly dally and 0 responses.

Remember that REST callback functions must return a value, not echo it.